# Given a list of lists, find matching pairs and append to a third list for each nested-list in list

Tags: python-3.x

Bear with me for the title but I couldn't figure out another way to word it. I have a list of lists where each nested-list is a list of strings, a list for comparing, and a third empty list to populate.

```py
dblr = [['5axE', 'iBeTT', 'iCat', 'AGTTTGATAT', "3AmA"], ['5YyLL', 'iDub', 'GTTGACCTAC', 'iDub', "3BQ"], ['5YyLL', 'iDub', 'GTTGACCTAC', 'iDub']]
c = ["3AmA", "3BQ"]
t = []

for li in dblr:
   for st in li:
      if st in c:
         t.append(st)
      else:
         t.append("None")
```

What I'm trying to do is see if a string in `dblr` exists in `c`, and if it does then I want to add that string to `list t` in the same order as the nested-lists in `dblr`. However, if the string doesn't exist in the nested-list, then I just want to append "None" to the `list t`. For the case above, the expected output is

```
["3AmA", "3BQ", "None"]
```

Since the first two arrays contained the string but the third didn't. However, the output I'm receiving is

```
["None", "None", "None", "None", "3AmA", "None", "None",  "None", "None", "3BQ", "None", "None", "None", "None"]
```

which I believe is due to the loop iterating over each string.

Is there a way to loop through the strings to evaluate, but to only iterate and append `len(dblr)` times so that `"None"` isn't being appended for each string in each list in `dblr`? While also mirroring the order of `dblr`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
dblr = [['5axE', 'iBeTT', 'iCat', 'AGTTTGATAT', "3AmA"], ['5YyLL', 'iDub', 'GTTGACCTAC', 'iDub', "3BQ"], ['5YyLL', 'iDub', 'GTTGACCTAC', 'iDub']]
c = ["3AmA", "3BQ"]
t = []

for li in dblr:
    found = False
    for st in c:
        if st in li:
            t.append(st)
            found = True
    if not found:
        t.append("None")

print(t)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dblr = [['5axE', 'iBeTT', 'iCat', 'AGTTTGATAT', "3AmA"], ['5YyLL', 'iDub', 'GTTGACCTAC', 'iDub', "3BQ"], ['5YyLL', 'iDub', 'GTTGACCTAC', 'iDub']]
c = ["3AmA", "3BQ"]
t = []
for each_list in dblr:
    for target in c:
        if target in each_list:
            t.append(target)
            break
    else:
        t.append("None")

print(t)
```

But it's not perfect when any list of `dblr` has more than one item which is in `c`.

example:

`dblr = [['5axE', 'iBeTT', 'iCat', 'AGTTTGATAT', "3AmA", "3BQ"], ...]`

result:

`['3AmA', '3BQ', 'None']`

To solve it, You can try this:

```
for each_list in dblr:
    inter = [i for i in each_list if i in c]
    if len(inter) < 1:
        inter = "None"
    elif len(inter) == 1:
        inter = inter[0]
    t.append(inter)
```

Then you can got the result as:

`[['3AmA', '3BQ'], '3BQ', 'None']`